# ¿Cómo contar palabras en una cadena o arreglo?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

Escribir en lenguaje C++ un programa que solicite el ingreso de un texto (máximo 500 palabras)
El programa deberá mostrar: el texto ingresado, las palabras del texto que se repiten y cuantas veces se repite cada una, con el siguiente formato:
En el texto “texto” las palabras que se repiten son:

nnnnnnn xx veces

nnnnnnn xx veces

nnnnnnn xx veces

Hasta el momento llevo esto

A la hora de mostrar en pantalla el conteo de las palabras, hay una que se cuentan de mas y otras que ni se cuentan, ¿cómo puedo resolver ese problema?

[image: Compilacion del codigo]

Como se puede observar, las palabras "sintaxis" y "de" se repiten dos veces pero no se muestra en el conteo inferior

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    void repetir(char[500]);
    void bg(char[250][500],int[250]);
    void busc_arreglo(char[500]);
    void sort(char[250][500],int[250]);
    void priw(char[250][500],int[250]);
    
    void repetir(char texto[500])
    {
        int i, j, k;
        int cont[250];
        char plbr[250][500];
        char aux[500];
        
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n El texto escrito es ");
        putchar('"');
        printf("%s", texto);
        putchar('"');
        
        bg(plbr, cont);
        
        for(i = 0; texto[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            busc_arreglo(aux);
            for(k = 0; texto[i]>='A'&& texto[i] <= 'Z' || texto[i]>='a' && texto[i] <= 'z';)
            {
                if(texto[i] >= 'A' && texto[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                    aux[k++] = texto[i++] + 32;
                }
                else
                {
                    aux[k++] = texto[i++];
                }
                aux[k]='\0';                
            }
            if(aux[0]!='\0')
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 250;)
                {
                    if(strcmp(plbr[j],aux) == 0)
                    {
                        cont[j]++;
                        j = 251;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(plbr[j][0]=='\0')
                        {
                            strcpy(plbr[j],aux);
                            cont[j]++;
                            j = 251;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            j++;
                        }               
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        printf("\n Palabras repetidas\n\n");
        sort(plbr, cont);
        priw(plbr, cont);
    }
    
    void bg(char plbr[250][500], int cont[250])
    {
        int i;
        
        for(i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            plbr[i][0]='\0';
            cont[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    void busc_arreglo(char aux[500])
    {
        aux[0]='\0';
    }
    
    void sort(char plbr[250][500], int cont[250])
    {   
        int i, j, m;
        char aux[500];
        
        for(i = 0; i < 249; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 249-i; j++)
            {
                if(plbr[j + 1][0]!='\0')
                {
                    if(strcmp(plbr[j], plbr[j + 1]) > 0)
                    {
                        strcpy(aux, plbr[j]);
                        m = cont[j];
                        strcpy(plbr[j], plbr[j + 1]);
                        cont[j] = cont[i + 1];
                        strcpy(plbr[j + 1], aux);
                        cont[j + 1] = m;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    j = 250;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    void priw(char plbr[250][500], int cont[250])
    {   
        int i;
        
        for(i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            if(cont[i] > 1)
            {
                printf("\n La palabra ");
                putchar('"');
                printf("%s", plbr[i]);
                putchar('"');
                printf(" se repite %d veces.", cont[i]);    
            }
        }
    }
    
    int main()
    {   
        char texto[500];
        
        printf("\n Ingrese un texto menor a 500 caracteres:\n\n ");
        gets(texto);
        
        repetir(texto);
        
        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Si realmente estás en C++. Usa la librería estándar. `iostream` para entrada y salida y la clase [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) para cadenas. El procedimiento no es muy difícil: identifica las palabras, ponlas en una lista y luego usa un diccionario ([`map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)) para llevar la cuenta de las repeticiones de cada una.

Comment: @jose-alejandro-varon-carreño c != c++.

Answer (score 1):

Aprovechando que el operador de indexado (`operator[]`) del mapa inserta elementos si no existen u obtiene el elemento si existe, puedes leer el texto con un flujo de texto y usar un mapa:

```
std::stringstream texto{"Esto es un examen de sintaxis y sintaxis es una manteria de segundo año. Y para nosotros es necesario aprobarlo"};

std::map<std::string, int> recuento;
std::string palabra;

while (texto >> palabra)
    ++recuento[palabra];

for (const auto &kvp : recuento)
    std::cout << "La palabra \"" << kvp.first << "\" se repite " << kvp.second << " veces\n";
```

El código anterior [produce la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##VY9NbsIwEIXX@BQjV6pAtKhriLLrrheoSheDM1CLZMbyD6VCHKpn6MFSJxB@dvbM@96bZ5x73hjTtg@WTZ0qgsJKiJ6wKdV11qC7/WaB5c3dZGCU5QgNWh5P1EGNQqzm85P8pIBI@ygH/RqiAAVIDLTHhhiyTcgw7m2An@uz12C25EjeYi@jTeJKAP9@ZQbv4NAjsASJXnqAyVBAb7PEeVmhr0UfF@p8Ti5T3Nz1BDmqBE8mEUdZ3B2dvWtceezg7y9bE4z7AlCWw2qiRqPpdMA/ztPPjliLh7ERDhEwZehxu3Mwv0R1ZJ9lJEUoCtBvOLjCUutulInZ2vpw2i91Lp95ZyPBZR8oZ1S9AHZd9SXrLt5TTJ7hZaGObfsP):

> ```
> La palabra "Esto" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "Y" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "aprobarlo" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "año." se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "de" se repite 2 veces
> La palabra "es" se repite 3 veces
> La palabra "examen" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "manteria" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "necesario" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "nosotros" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "para" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "segundo" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "sintaxis" se repite 2 veces
> La palabra "un" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "una" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "y" se repite 1 veces
> ```

Si necesitas ignorar los signos de puntuación e ignorar mayúsculas/minúsculas deberás pre-procesar la palabra:

```
while (texto >> palabra)
{
    std::transform(palabra.begin(), palabra.end(), palabra.begin(), [](char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    std::remove_if(palabra.begin(), palabra.end(), [](char c) { return !(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'); });
    ++recuento[palabra];
}
```

Lo que produce [la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##hVFLbttADF1Hp2BVwJaQ1OjaUrXrrhcI4qCgR7Q8iDQUOCPHqeFD9Qw9mEtJluMgAbKbId@PpGnbb5Uxp9NX60zdlQS5ZR@EsCmi11qD7fVXAdZVbyrvOVhXLDZstRhZF6BB65I0OkQ3PpTL5agx0iDQPvAh/ukDA3noHNAeG3KgQl7JuLceXl6fAwZV0gUSiwOMqs6VDPjvLy/gHloUBMeeg/BAcGTIo1iFtMJrlJrjYxad4@iE@VWuO1CrAoRMRy5w9ia0ate4FuzJz1tbEyTDAFAUUyuNbnTQkRQEnd@wNMm5uVhT1e/ibkIvyJXX30v/4TExWxQwKRw0TOjEwajJNT@TJCbN4Jhmk5VQwzv6bTefWn2k/CUxUPyAOc5hNgMDub7/zC8Ot7fTOh7OYo9aPuoSdDhIDDsfADvdw@xp18Lysr10ime4C5DnEP/CKQ@s4rgvKWOxseLH/irWeyq/tYHg0vekHuUAgF1/zZWL@xuc43/PouPp9B8):

> ```
> La palabra "ao±o." se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "aprobarlo" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "de" se repite 2 veces
> La palabra "es" se repite 3 veces
> La palabra "esto" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "examen" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "manteria" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "necesario" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "nosotros" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "para" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "segundo" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "sintaxis" se repite 2 veces
> La palabra "un" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "una" se repite 1 veces
> La palabra "y" se repite 2 veces
> ```